# How can I make bat file open Excel files with quotes?

Tags: windows, batch-file

- Excel is installed at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\EXCEL.EXE`
- Folder where the files is at `C:\Heffalump files`
- The name of a example file is `Auto the heff.xlsx`

Been toying with a bat file to run that excel file but cant get it to work. The above should have been

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\EXCEL.EXE" "C:\Heffalump\Auto the heff.xlsx"
```

when running the bat:

```
"C:\MyAwesomeBat.bat" "Auto the heff.xlsx"
```

But it keeps the quotes so it gets all messed up.

```
cls
@SET ScheduledExcel=true
@SET ScheduledExcelFolder="C:\Heffalump files"
@SET ScheduledExcelFilePath=%ScheduledExcelFolder%\%1

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\EXCEL.EXE" %ScheduledExcelFilePath%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enclose the entire argument into quotes, not only parts of it. Your 2nd `SET` statement includes the quotes into the value; after appending `%1`, you'll have a quote in the value.

The following should work:

```
CLS
@SET ScheduledExcel=true
@SET "ScheduledExcelFolder=C:\Heffalump files"
@SET "ScheduledExcelFilePath=%ScheduledExcelFolder%\%~1"

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\EXCEL.EXE" "%ScheduledExcelFilePath%"
```

I enclosed the *entire* `SET` expression in quotes, so they do not become part of the value.

Note also the `~` in `%~1` which removes surrounding quotes if there are any.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you set a variable to a string, it's generally good practice to quote the `set "variable=value"` pair.  That way the value doesn't contain the quotes, but you also avoid evaluating tricky characters like `&`.  Then you can explicitly quote at retrieval time when needed.

Also, aschipfl correctly points out that you need to include a tilde in `%~1` to strip the surrounding quotes from the command-line argument.

```
@echo off
setlocal

cls
SET "ScheduledExcel=true"
SET "ScheduledExcelFolder=C:\Heffalump files"
SET "ScheduledExcelFilePath=%ScheduledExcelFolder%\%~1"

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\EXCEL.EXE" "%ScheduledExcelFilePath%"
```

For what it's worth, unless you intentionally installed Office to that folder, isn't Office typically located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15` or similar?  Regardless, as Mahran hinted, you don't actually need to specify the full path to `excel.exe`.  If Windows has .xlsx files associated with Excel, then you can either

```
start "" "%ScheduledExcelFilePath%"
```

or

```
call "%ScheduledExcelFilePath%"
```

or most simply

```
"%ScheduledExcelFilePath%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply on you bat file write this code

```
call C:\Heffalump\heff.xlsx
```